# Save iPython Jupyter Notebook Widgets to PNG/PDF/JPG/GIF

Tags: widget, ipython, png, jupyter, gif

I was just wondering, if there's some way how to automatically save the content of the cell (including the cell output) to a PNG/PDF/JPG/GIF. I'd be happy with any of the alternatives.
For documentation purposes I'd like to save the state of a VBox/Hbox containing multiple iPython Widgets. There are many possible combinations of the widgets settings, I can iterate over these settings with my code, but I'd like the corresponding visual setting of the widgets to any of the possible above mentioned formats for documentation purposes.
I've looked into html2canvas, but I'm not sure if it's the right solution for me. As well, using the ipython convert to HTML doesn't output the widgets for me.
Many thanks in advance for any hint.
Regards

Josef