# Programmatically save Ipython widget to a file as image

Tags: python, widget, save-image

I am just trying to programmatically save displayed widget on my computer. I tried to use capture as well as output. I wish there was method called .savefig()

I have seen this question, [Save iPython Jupyter Notebook Widgets to PNG/PDF/JPG/GIF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54441389/save-ipython-jupyter-notebook-widgets-to-png-pdf-jpg-gif) but there is no answer.

I am just trying to save the slider object to my computer file system such as myimage.jpeg

[image]

Here is the code

```
import ipywidgets as wg
from IPython.display import display
w = wg.IntSlider(description='Test Slider',min=1,max=25)
w.value=14
display(w)


#Question is how to save this test slider as image output ??
```